# Could I help users update all the extensions they installed from my extension?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I recently developed an extension called [Better Extension Manager](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/gnnggbedbbegbdnmimdhkhkfdcikfnjl) to provide an alternative of Chrome's extension manager, with some improvement like search and operate on more than one extensions at one time.
Some users advise that it would be better to have a "update all extensions now" option, I couldn't find APIs from the document to do this. Am I missing something?

Comment: All I can help you with is that in the original extensions page, the "Update" button does this javaScript:
`function autoUpdate() {
  chrome.send('autoupdate', []);
}`

Comment: Yes, I've looked at it. it seems that only Chrome's page can use the function chrome.send

Answer (score -1):

You might be able to do this with a NPAPI plugin but otherwise will have to open a feature request. http://new.crbug.com